# Unable to deploy meteor 1.9 on Digital Ocean using mup

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, mup

I have been trying to deploy meteor 1.9 application on digital ocean droplet via mup but I am not able to do.
The issue occurs with sharp installation if I use abernix/meteord:base image.
If I use other image with a different node version I get bcrypt installation error.
This is my mup file.

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
      host: "server IP",
      username: "root",

      password: "my password"
      // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: "appName",
    path: ".",

    servers: {
      one: {}
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      PORT: 2010,
      ROOT_URL: "my url",
      MONGO_URL: "mongodb://mongodb/meteor",
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: "mongodb://mongodb/local"
    },

    docker: {
      // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
      image: "abernix/meteord:base",
      prepareBundle: false
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: "3.4.1",
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }

};
```

*this is the error log if I use latest image abernix/meteord:node-12.14.0-base*

```
[192.241.152.237]> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs2/node_modules/core-js
[192.241.152.237]> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
[192.241.152.237]> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]> bcrypt@4.0.1 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
[192.241.152.237]> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
[192.241.152.237][bcrypt] Success: "/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]> sharp@0.24.1 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sharp
[192.241.152.237]> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
[192.241.152.237]
[192.241.152.237]ERR! sharp 'darwin-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'linux-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp/vendor' directory and run 'npm install'.
[192.241.152.237]info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
[192.241.152.237]info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
[192.241.152.237]make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sharp/build'
[192.241.152.237]  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/metadata.o
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/stats.o
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/operations.o
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/pipeline.o
[192.241.152.237]  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/sharp.o
```

Comment: Which Metwor version do you use? The aberbix image needs to meet the node version used by Meteor, which you find out in your Meteor project using `meteor node -v`

Comment: Which Ubuntu version on the digital ocean is used?

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

After re-reading the issue, and looking at your error message closer it looks like the sharp binaries installed are for MacOS and it's trying to build them for Linux and potentially failing.

If you haven't already, you might try either destroying the current droplet and reusing mup to set it up, OR you could spin up Linux in a VM or a separate droplet and build on an equivalent system and then deploy from there.

Comment: Which version of sharp and bcrypt you are using